Changing Flutter Date Picker Locale
I'm trying to integrate different date formats across screens based on user preferences,

DD/MM/YYYY
MM/DD/YYYY
YYYY/MM/DD

Flutter's showDatePicker function has an input field with which user can enter a text.
I want to specifically change the default showDatePicker input format  according to the selected date format.
This should include handling dateformat validations.

I was able to change the format to by passing different Locale,
and also apply format validations
Locale('en', 'GB') for DD/MM/YYYY
Locale('en', 'US') (default) for MM/DD/YYYY
I want to know which Locale supports YYYY/MM/DD format

There is no predefined locale in Flutter’s intl package that uses the YYYY/MM/DD format. You can format dates in this way manually using DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd').

I need the showDatePicker text input field to accept date in yyyy/mm/dd format as well


Flutter directly doesn't support YYYY/MM/DD format, You need to write your custom way to get it by using Intlplugin.

This is the way you can integrate it,
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  TextEditingController dateController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Devraj Sample POC'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: dateController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enter date (YYYY/MM/DD)',
                hintText: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: [
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
                DateTextInputFormatter(),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DateTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    String text = newValue.text;

    // Remove any non-digit characters
    text = text.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9]'), '');

    // Format as YYYY/MM/DD
    if (text.length > 4 && text[4] != '/') {
      text = '${text.substring(0, 4)}/${text.substring(4)}';
    }
    if (text.length > 7 && text[7] != '/') {
      text = '${text.substring(0, 7)}/${text.substring(7)}';
    }

    if (text.length > 10) {
      text = text.substring(0, 10);
    }

    return TextEditingValue(
      text: text,
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: text.length),
    );
  }
}

